# DBT Model hanging

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

I use macOS and I am having issue with full-refresh on a large table. During the run it appears as if it hangs and there is no query running in redshift. It does not happen with smaller tables and it does not happen if I run an incremental. This table used to be smaller and I was able to run a full refresh as long as I specified the table. Now that it is bigger I seem to be running into this issue. There are 6 tables that this model is dependent on. Almost like the command isn’t being sent. Any suggestions?
There is no error because it just doesn't run. Other team members running this on windows and macos expect it to finish in 10 min. Currently it is 30 min but I have let it sit a lot longer than that.
My command is
`dbt run --models +fct_mymodel --full-refresh --vars "run_date_start: 2020-06-01"`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Redhift UI usually shows only the long running queries. I ran into similar problems and they were caused by lock on some tables - in our case caused by uncommitted explicit transactions (`BEGIN` without `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`).

run this query to see current transactions and their locks:

```
select a.txn_owner, a.txn_db, a.xid, a.pid, a.txn_start, a.lock_mode, a.relation as table_id,nvl(trim(c."name"),d.relname) as tablename, a.granted,b.pid as blocking_pid ,datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())/86400||' days '||datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())%86400/3600||' hrs '||datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())%3600/60||' mins '||datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())%60||' secs' as txn_duration
from svv_transactions a 
left join (select pid,relation,granted from pg_locks group by 1,2,3) b 
on a.relation=b.relation and a.granted='f' and b.granted='t' 
left join (select * from stv_tbl_perm where slice=0) c 
on a.relation=c.id 
left join pg_class d on a.relation=d.oid
where  a.relation is not null;
```

read AWS knowledge base entry for more details https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-locks-blocking-queries-redshift/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did find some exclusive locks but no blocking pids. I think it still might be in the right direction. There are 3 staging tables that work off the same partitioned table. That is the lock. Those are finishing in about 20 min. Then there is a fact table that is built from those three tables. That never starts. If I run just that it does finish. I just noticed the fact table logic is using a materialized view and sort so going there next.

Comment: Did you check the `logs/dbt.log` whether the query is issued by dbt? It seems like it's not sure whether the Redshift query, or the dbt process is hanging.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... i did go through them and didn't see anything helpful but I had to move on for a little while. Will try to address again on monday because I actually need it to work! Thanks!